# Community Promotion Ad

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Using a banner (the most highly voted one), from [this](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/312/creating-an-ad-for-community-promotion) question, I have posted the banner as a community promotion ad on several sites. If the ads get six upvotes, then they will be displayed on the main site. I will post the links here if you wish to vote.

And thanks to overactor for creating the banner! Which is this one below:

[image]

Comment: One more upvote for Sci-Fi.SE and RPG.SE and then it appears on the site!

Comment: I notice on the physics.SE meta question there is a [remarkably similar ad](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/5265/48853) for astrobites.org. Not a problem, just interesting...

Comment: @githubphagocyte Yeah it is. And to everyone else, congrats. Our ad is now showing up RPG.SE and Scifi.SE.

Comment: I've just upvoted on physics.SE so only 2 more needed now...

Comment: You have "sicfi" instead of "sci-fi" - I don't have privileges to edit it myself, so I point to this typo here.

Comment: @PavelV. I did that because that is the way the link forms, besides sci-fi probably doesn't have an "official" spelling.

Comment: Sorry, the hyphen confused you. Once again: it should be "scifi", not "sicfi".

Comment: @PavelV. Oh, I see. Thanks.

Comment: It's great that we're getting visibility on other SE sites -- good job! I'd like to urge just a bit of caution; the community-promotion ads are meant to be things that members of the host site want to run ads for, so if you find yourself joining another site *just* to vote on ads, without otherwise participating, ask yourself if that's being a good neighbor. We should talk up WB, we should participate on sites where we want to participate, and we shouldn't push our agenda overly. Only graduated sites get ads so this is *probably* ok; they'll have more users than us. But consider appearances.

Comment: @MonicaCellio the original three sites were all one's I honestly thought the community would be interested in, the same for the other sites that I've reactor posted it on. But good words, we'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Please don't take my comment as criticism of any individuals; that wasn't the intent.  I posted it out of concern for *future* action; I've seen a few comments in chat about going to other sites to vote up ads and I want us to try to do that only on sites that we're actually part of in some way, is all.  And, again, it's *great* that we've got so much visibility out there so far!

Comment: For 2016, ads (including community ads) are being resized: 300x250 instead of the current 220x250 (so, slightly landscape now rather than portrait).  We're going to need a new version of this -- or a new ad, if people prefer -- to submit to other sites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### 2017

[This ad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrIsG.png) has made it past the threshold on

- [SciFi](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10566/41082)
- [RPG](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6728)
- [Game Dev](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2362/98889)

This ad has also been posted on

- (No other sites)

Possible targets are

- [Physics](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9554/56299)
- [Arqade](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12230)
- ???

Answer (score 9):

### 2014

I'm happy to announce that we made it past the threshold on 5 sites now:

- [RPG.SE](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5067/16488)
- [Scifi.SE](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5116/33055)
- [GameDev.SE](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1408/community-promotion-ads-2014/1764#1764)
- [Physics.SE](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6211/60884)
- [Gaming.SE](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8040/community-promotion-ads-2014/10016#10016)

The ad has also been posted at:

- currently no sites where it is not past the threshold.

Note that this is a community wiki, feel free to edit as you vote on our ad or if you post an ad elsewhere.

Comment: Up-voted on Physics to bring the score to 6. We're good to go there!

Comment: Down voted again on Phsyics

Comment: Upvoted again on Physics :)

Answer (score 2):

### 2016

(Note: the image in the question here is no longer the one being used; ad requirements chaanged.)

It's late in the year, I know, but I was looking for the list of sites where we currently have ads and didn't find it, so maybe we didn't compile it for 2016.  If you have a link to the **2016 ad for Worldbuilding** on some other site, please add it here.

- [RPG](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6033/19667)
- [SciFi](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7993/32756)

It looks like we did not submit an ad to Physics in 2016.

Answer (score 0):

### 2015

A new year means new community-ad posts that have to be voted on again.  This ad is fairly new so I don't think we need to change anything about it (if you disagree please speak up), but it *will* need to be resubmitted to other sites.

This ad has made it past the threshold on:

- [SciFi](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5355/32756)
- [RPG](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5293/19667)
- [Physics](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388/community-promotion-ads-2015/6400#6400)

Comment: I don't have accounts on the other sites we used last year, so somebody else please do those.  Also please watch out for the tagline; someone in chat found that it said "great RPGs have great worlds" *on SciFi*, which was probably a cut/paste glitch.  That might not go over so well on, say, Physics.

Comment: I added the ad on Physics; it went over really well last year.

Comment: Upvoted on Physics.